# Estuviste vs Has Estado

Tags: pretérito-imperfecto, pretérito-perfecto

I wanted to ask a question about the difference between *estuviste* and *Has estado*.

I was asked to complete the following sentence:

> ¿(tú, estar) alguna vez en Colombia?

I answered as:

> ¿Estuviste alguna vez en Colombia?

implying the indefinido.

However, the apparent correct answer is

> ¿Has estado alguna vez en Colombia?

and I'm confused as to why this subtlety means my answer is wrong.

I thought that as a visit to Colombia has now finished, the question should be worded using the indefinido but apparently the correct tense is the imperfecto.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is ‘Has estado’ because the sentence says ‘alguna vez’. You use ‘pretérito perfecto simple’ when there’s a localized situation in the temporal line. for example: if you went to latin america and now you’re back, and we are talking about your trip i can ask you ‘¿Estuviste en Colombia?’ because i know you were in latin america in a certain moment... You use ‘pretérito perfecto compuesto’ when the action have taken place in an uncertain moment in the past. so, ‘¿Has estado en Colombia?’ means that you have ever been in Colombia. ‘alguna vez’.

The Grammar of RAE says:
« 23.4.1a He cantado es un antepresente en la terminología de Andrés Bello. Este término expresa la anterioridad de la situación denotada con respecto a un punto de referencia situado en el presente, lo que lo caracteriza como tiempo relativo. Así pues, en la llamada interpretación de antepresente, he cantado se usa para hacer referencia a ciertas situaciones pretéritas, sean puntuales o durativas. Estas situaciones tienen lugar en un intervalo que se abre en un punto inespecífio del pasado y se prolonga hasta el momento de la enunciación y lo incluye (propiedad que recoge también la denominación ahora extendido: § 23.3.1a, b). Como consecuencia, las situaciones son evaluadas o medidas desde el momento del habla.

23.5.1a El pretérito perfecto simple localiza una situación en un punto de la línea temporal que es anterior al momento del habla. Con canté las situaciones se presentan completas o acabadas. Debe, pues, suponerse que se alcanzan los límites inicial y fial del evento con los predicados internamente delimitados. Así pues, la oración Arturo leyó Guerra y paz el mes pasado expresa —frente a la variante con leía— que la lectura de la novela se completó. Igualmente, en Pese a la oscuridad, alcanzó la puerta (Sepúlveda, L., Viejo), con un predicado de consecución o logro, se interpreta que se llegó a la puerta que se menciona.»